# Insert into C++ map leads to infinite recursion?

Tags: c++, c, trace

I'm trying to write some code that will allow me to insert into a C++ map from an `extern "C"` function. The code is as follows:

```
class CFITracing {
    std::unordered_map<uintptr_t, uintptr_t> CallerCalleePairs;
    std::map<std::string, int> BranchResults;

public:
    void HandleCallerCallee(uintptr_t Caller, uintptr_t Callee);
    void HandleBranchResult(int cond, char* branchName);

    void printResults();
};

...

void CFITracing::HandleBranchResult(int cond, char* branchName) {
    std::string branchStr(branchName);
    printf("%s\n", "pre");

    /* segfault at this line, regardless of what string I use as a key (even "hi") */
    BranchResults[branchStr] = cond; 

    printf("%s\n", "success");
}

CFITracing CFIT;


__attribute__((used))
__attribute__((optnone))
extern "C" void __trace(int cond, char* branchName) {
    CFIT.HandleBranchResult(cond, branchName);
}
```

Calls to the `__trace` function are inserted into the binary via an LLVM pass I've written, which passes an `int` and `char*` to my code above.

On calls to `__trace`,  `"pre"` is printed repeatedly until a segmentation fault occurs. GDB shows that, when the line with the map insert occurs, the code somehow loops and this line is called repeatedly until the segfault occurs.

When debugging via valgrind, the following error occurs:

```
==20881== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0x1ffe801000
==20881== 
==20881== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==20881==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1FFE801FF8
==20881== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0x1ffe801000
==20881==    at 0x58069A2: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1220)
```

The presence of a stack overflow, together with the repeated prints, make me think infinite recursion has been triggered. I think it's likely I've created some type of undefined behavior, but I'm not sure exactly how to write this code to prevent it, given that I need to insert into the map via this `extern "C" __trace()` function.

Thus, my questions are as follows: is there anything quick I can fix to prevent this behavior from taking place? If not, how should I aim to redesign this, given that I need to insert into the map via the `extern "C"` function? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You said that you're inserting calls to `__trace` in a non-standard manner. Have you made sure those calls correctly handle the registers and comply with the correct calling convention?

Comment: you cast to std::string branchStr(branchName); and where do you use it? can you show implementation of branchStr()?

Comment: and is this multithreaded code? are you sure that the pointer is valid at the time you use it to insert into the map?

Comment: @rsjaffe I am inserting these calls with an LLVM compiler pass into LLVM IR, and the LLVM verifier allows this to compile, so I think register handling is below the level of abstraction at which I insert the calls. Also, when I remove the map insert, the program works as intended, so the __trace call itself does not seem to cause issues.

Comment: sure the problem is here `std::string branchStr(branchName);` what happens insidethis function with branchName? because you do actually `BranchResults[char*branchName] = cond;`

Comment: @OlSen My bad, I pasted an earlier version of the code before I caught that mistake! I'll edit the question - I am using branchStr in the current version of the code, and the error still occurs

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @rsjaffe I can print out the string before I insert it into the map and it prints a valid string each time, so I don't believe it's an issue with the pointer being invalid

Comment: Sure sounds like you have undefined behavior somehow, and we're not seeing the part of the code causing that. I'd pick at the char * some more: that's the most likely culprit. Have you placed a breakpoint in HandleBranchResult and examined what the pointer is actually pointing to?

Comment: And is it possible that two calls to HandleBranchResult are occurring at the same time?

Comment: Have you made sure that your compiler pass isn't inserting calls to `__trace` inside `std::unordered_map<uintptr_t, uintptr_t>::operator[]`? That seems like the most obvious culprit. If you can disable the compiler pass and a manual call to `__trace` doesn't cause it to break, then the problem probably just lies in the compiler pass making `__trace` infinitely recursive. I say this because it looks like `__trace` is annotating branches, which are everywhere. EDIT: Scary thought: do you end up with two differing copies of the `unordered_map` template?

Comment: @rsjaffe GDB shows that the pointer is valid and points to a string each time. However, each time I break at the line in question and go to the next line, GDB just shows me the same line again - the infinite recursion issue in effect.

Comment: @rsjaffe My code is not explicitly written to be multithreaded, so I'm not sure how two simultaneous calls may occur, but if you have any suggestions about to investigate further I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @HTNW I didn't think about that, but it makes a lot of sense. The code is indeed annotating branches, and I can check if __trace calls are there, which would create the kind of infinite recursion you discuss. Thanks for pointing this out!

I'm not sure what you mean by two differing copies of the unordered_map template: how would something like that occur?

Comment: @jdav22 If the compiler pass makes `__trace` recursive, the obvious fix would be to just disable the pass while compiling the file that contains `__trace`. But this would still be broken: now the object file containing `__trace` will contain one compiled version of the `std::unordered_map` specialization (without calls to `__trace`) and another file may use the same specialization, but would generate compiled code that does call `__trace`. Upon linking, it's anyone's guess which you'll get. `__trace` is too low-level to blindly use "external" libraries (including C++'s standard library).

Comment: ```__trace``` is provided a name for the function containing the branch, and the function has a very long name but makes mentions to ```__Rb_tree```, which means it's quite likely being invoked downstream due to the use of the [] operator. For my purposes I only need to annotate branches that exist in user-written code, not in collections used by said code. I wonder if LLVM provides a convenient way to differentiate - something I can look into. Thanks for your help!